# casting in method java

Tags: java, arrays, casting

I have problem with the toArray method. In this example i am using Integer and solved it by casting Integer, but the method should work for all types, without casting in main.

why cant i use one of these two in my main method?

```
arr = (T[]) a.toArray(arr) ;
```

or even

```
arr = a.toArray(arr)
```

I get a type mismatch: cannot convert from object[] to Integer[]

both size() and addFirst() works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayDeque a = new ArrayDeque(5);
    a.addFirst(1);
    a.addFirst(2);

    Integer [] arr = new Integer[a.size()];
    arr=  (Integer[]) a.toArray(arr);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));   
}



public class ArrayDeque<E> implements IDeque<E> {

    private int counter= 0;
    private E[] deque;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ArrayDeque(int size) {
      deque = (E[]) new Object[size];
  }


public <E> E[] toArray(E[] a) {
    return (E[]) Arrays.copyOf(deque, counter, a.getClass());
    }

}
```

Comment: note that `toArray`'s `<E>` hides a class type parameter `E`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are instantiating a raw type:

```
ArrayDeque a = new ArrayDeque(5);
```

change it to

```
ArrayDeque<Integer> a = new ArrayDeque<>(5);
```

This will remove the need to cast the returned array to `Integer[]`.

P.S., it doesn't make sense for the `toArray(E[] a)` to define its own generic type parameter `E`. It should use the parameter defined in the class level.

Comment: You are answering a (pretty obvious?) dup ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating a raw type when declaring the ArrayDeque a. You should parameterize it:

```
ArrayDeque<Integer> a = new ArrayDeque<Integer>(5);
a.addFirst(1);
a.addFirst(2);

Integer [] arr = new Integer[a.size()];
arr=  a.toArray(arr);
```